# forward and back command

Tags: python

wanted to know how to write a forward and back command in a superclass not sure but i gave it a try dont know if its right or wrong some help plz

```
def forward(self):
  return (self.100)

def back(self):
  return (self.50)
```

Comment: We'll need a bit more information. What do you mean by move? Have you got some member-variables keeping track of position? What does forward mean in the context of your program?

Comment: @hugh: neither your code nor comment make any sense

Comment: `100` is not a valid variable name in Python, the same with `50`.

Comment: 1. Please run through a Python tutorial or something before you ask Python questions. --- 2. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18584/how-to-ask-a-smart-question-on-so/25128#25128 ---- 3. http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Comment: What are these commands supposed to do?

Answer (score 1):

```
def forward(self):
  self.position += self.distance
  return (self.position)

def back(self):
  self.position -= self.distance
  return (self.position)
```

EDIT:
I assumed you are doing something like progress bar of install app, where some operation advances progress (copying files), and if user cancels install others operation make rollback (deleting files). Try ask a proper question as other users comment.

Comment: Also note this may not work correctly with floating point calculations. Your better of pushing and poping the float values onto a command pattern to keep the same floating point calculation accuracy.

Comment: what does the second line of code do "self.position += self.distance"